# Kotlin: An elegant way to check if a List contains a value of another Collection / List?

Tags: kotlin

Is there an elegant / idiomatic way to check in Kotlin whether an element of one list is contained in another list?

Given:

```
val listA = listOf("A", "B", "C")
```

I can write expressions such as:

```
listA.intersect(setOf("E", "C")).isNotEmpty()
```

or:

```
listA.any { it in listOf("E","C") }
```

That's OK, but I wonder if there is even a more fluent way to express that (as this code is simplified, the real code is more complex).

My fallback is to use a custom extension function, e.g.:

```
fun <T> List<T>.containsAny(vararg other : T) =
      this.intersect(other.toSet()).isNotEmpty()
```

I just wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: I'm not sure what you see as undesirable about `setA.any {it in setB}`.

Comment: Our business logic is very complex, and any relief we can provide in it for the random reader - it preferred.

Comment: What is complex about that line of code?

Comment: OK. That's fair. I edited the question to reflect the case more reliably. We originally used lists and moving to sets was a step trying to simplify the code a bit (but it still wasn't as good as we wanted).

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't want to pull out a constant for the inner list?  As it stands, writing listOf inside the lambda seems likely to harm performance.

Answer (score 21):

I agree with Louis that `setA.any { it in setB }` seems pretty readable, and relies solely on the standard library functions. Alternatively, you could use a method reference to make it a bit more explicit:

```
setA.any(setB::contains)
```

Straying a bit further, you could just define your own extension function:

```
infix fun <T: Any> Set<T>.intersects(other: Set<T>) = any(other::contains)
```

Then you can just write:

```
if (setA intersects setB)
```

EDIT: Given your updated question, I'd note that this extension function can scale to any collection type, or with your varargs approach:

```
infix fun <T: Any> Collection<T>.intersects(other: Collection<T>) = any(other::contains)
fun <T: Any> Collection<T>.intersects(vararg others: T) = any(other::contains)
```

So you can still do something like:

```
if (myList intersects setOf("1", "2", "3"))
```

or

```
if (myList.intersects("1", "2", "3"))
```